# Sql Query using multiple inserts and multiple LAST_INSERT_ID() 's is not working

Tags: php, mysql, last-insert-id

Hi guys I'm trying to store questions & answers in 2 tables using 1 sql query:

```
INSERT INTO questions ( question, level_ID ) VALUES ( 'hello', '1'); INSERT INTO answers (questions_ID, answer, ok) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),'doei',0), (LAST_INSERT_ID(),'ciao',1);
```

If I execute the code in PHPMyAdmin in a SQL box it works just fine but if I execute it in my PHP code generating script it returns the following error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO answers (questions_ID, answer, ok) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),'doei',0' at line 2

I cant't see what I'm doing wrong...anyone??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My guess is that you are executing all queries in a single call but you are using a library that does not support multiple statements.

Answer (score 1):

It is not SQL query but rather set of queries.
PHPmyAdmin just split your set and then execute queries separately.

So you have to do.
Just run them one after one.

Do not change anything. No need for extra variables or whatever.
Just run the very same queries one after another in 2 separate consecutive calls.
That's all.

Comment: ...or use [mysqli::multi_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php).

Comment: OK guys thanks. If I split up the queries and run them separate it works indeed. But since I need the generated id from LAST_INSERT_ID() I put the queries together. So now I have to probably use a variable to store the generated id?

Comment: @ArjoPost yes you need a variable to pass to the second SQL. you're done.

Comment: @ArjoPost - It doesn't make any difference, unless you close the database connection between two queries.

Answer (score 0):

From [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id):

> **The ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a
>   per-connection basis**. This means that the value returned by the
>   function to a given client is the first AUTO_INCREMENT value generated
>   for most recent statement affecting an AUTO_INCREMENT column by that
>   client. This value cannot be affected by other clients, even if they
>   generate AUTO_INCREMENT values of their own. This behavior ensures
>   that each client can retrieve its own ID without concern for the
>   activity of other clients, and without the need for locks or
>   transactions.

So you *don't need* to pack all queries into a SQL database call as long as you use the same connection. But if you *want* to do so, you need to ensure your database library and function support the feature.